# What are valid values for checkbox in Cold Fusion Form?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I'm new to ColdFusion and was wondering why my page breaks after I add a "-" for the value of the `<input type="checkbox">`?

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="food" value="check-fruit">

<CFPARAM NAME='form.check-fruit' Default=''>
```

But when I replaced the "-" with an underscore or just "fruit" it works fine. Anyone know why CFPARAM doesn't like it when I have a "-" in the value for the input?

Comment: shouldnt... that be `form.food`? `food` being the input's name?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7faf.html

Comment: If you specify a type, it will validate that the value matches said type. If no value exists and you specify a default, it will set the value to the default. If there is no default and there is no value, an exception will occur.

Comment: cfparam doesn't have a value parameter?

Comment: nvm I looked up what value is "The value attribute specifies the initial value for an input field:" why would you ever want to have pre-existing text in an input field though?

Comment: For cases where you want to specify a value beforehand, and for cases where you can't specify a value such as Checkboxes and radio buttons (which are instead checked or unchecked)

Comment: Can you use`form.['check-fruit']`?

Comment: ColdFusion only allows certain characters to be used in variable names.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html

Comment: I do not mean this sarcastically, but it is important to *read* error messages :) They are not always accurate, but in this case it tells you exactly what is wrong. The cfparam code throws this error: *".. Parameter 1 of function SetVariable, which is now form.check-fruit, must be a syntactically valid variable name."*. Combine that with the cfparam documentation, specifically the "Variable naming rules" section, it is clear the variable name (not "value") you are using is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute of a form field converts to a key in the `form` struct. The value of `form['name']` is the value of the form field's `value` attribute.

You can just do a `<cfdump var="#form#">` to see all of the field names and values submitted by the form (make sure to use POST and not GET as the form's `method`).

So you would do `<cfparam name="form.food" type="string" default="">` in order to set the default value for that field. Unless absolutely necessary, you don't need to set a `cfparam` for all of the fields, just the check boxes. If none are checked and you don't validate the field exists before you reference it, you'll get an error.